# Android ListActivity OnListItemClick error with Webviews

Tags: android, webview, listactivity

I've been figuring how to popup a webview all day when a row in my ListActivity is clicked. I can't even show a Toast when it's clicked. Need help

I'm still new with Android, a web developer trying to learn. Thanks before.

package com.mf.ar;

import org.json.JSONArray;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.app.ListActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.Window;
 import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
 import android.webkit.WebView;
 import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.Toast;

public class ListViewer extends ListActivity {
  private String mJSON;
  private String[] listRows;
  private String[] listRowsURI;

```
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     //setContentView(R.layout.listview);

     Bundle the = getIntent().getExtras();
     this.mJSON = the.getString("JSON");
     Log.i("ListViewIntentJSON", this.mJSON);

     try {
JSONObject UrbJSON = new JSONObject(mJSON);

JSONObject UrbQuery = UrbJSON.getJSONObject("query");
int rows = UrbQuery.getInt("row");
Log.i("UrbRows", String.format("%d",rows));

JSONArray resultArray = UrbJSON.getJSONArray("result");

this.listRows = new String[rows];
for(int i=0; i<rows; i++) { 
 this.listRows[i] = resultArray.getJSONObject(i).
   getString("business_name").toString();
}
this.listRowsURI = new String[rows];
for(int i=0; i<rows; i++) { 
 this.listRowsURI[i] = resultArray.getJSONObject(i).
   getString("business_uri_mobile").toString();
}
     } catch(JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }

     this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ListViewer.this.listRows));
 }

 @Override
 protected void onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
  super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

  String theURI = ListViewer.this.listRowsURI[position].toString();
  /*String theURI = ListViewer.this.listRowsURI[position].toString();
  //String theURI = "http://www.mediafusion.web.id";

  WebView webview = new WebView(this);
  //setContentView(webview);
  //addContentView(webview, null);
  webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
  final Activity activity = this;
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
  public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
    // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
    // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
    activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
  }
});
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
    Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
});
  webview.loadUrl(theURI);*/

  Toast.makeText(ListViewer.this.getApplicationContext(), theURI, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

 }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete all occurrences of `getApplicationContext()` in your code, and things will work better for you. `ListViewer` is a `Context` -- just use it in your `Toast`.

With respect to the `WebView`, I think you will be better served making that its own activity and starting that activity from `onListItemClick()`.

Comment: I've removed getApplicationContext() and instead used ListViewer.this but still the Toast won't show :(

Anyhow, I'm following your advice to make the webview its own activity. Will post more later :)

Comment: I've done what you told, it worked like a charm. Thank you for the pointers!